# How to listening contact changes in the phone book like adding a new contact,updating,deleting

Tags: android, android-contacts

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<SelectUser> selectUsers;
    List<SelectUser> temp;
    ListView listView;
    Cursor phones, email;
    public static final String INTENT_KEY_FINISH_ACTIVITY_ON_SAVE_COMPLETED = "finishActivityOnSaveCompleted";
    ContentResolver resolver;
    int INSERT_CONTACT_REQUEST = 2;
    SelectUserAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        selectUsers = new ArrayList<SelectUser>();
        resolver = this.getContentResolver();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);

        phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        LoadContact loadContact = new LoadContact();
        loadContact.execute();
        TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.AddHint);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

                i.putExtra(INTENT_KEY_FINISH_ACTIVITY_ON_SAVE_COMPLETED, true);
                startActivityForResult(i, INSERT_CONTACT_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    // Load data on background
    class LoadContact extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            // Get Contact list from Phone

            if (phones != null) {
                Log.e("count", "" + phones.getCount());
                if (phones.getCount() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No contacts in your contact list.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                    String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String EmailAddr = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA2));

                    SelectUser selectUser = new SelectUser();
                    selectUser.setName(name);
                    selectUser.setPhone(phoneNumber);
                    selectUser.setEmail(id);
                    selectUsers.add(selectUser);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Cursor close 1", "----------------");
            }
            //phones.close();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            adapter = new SelectUserAdapter(selectUsers, MainActivity.this);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Select item on listclick
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    Log.e("search", "here---------------- listener");

                    SelectUser data = selectUsers.get(i);
                }
            });

            listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        phones.close();
    }
}
```

How to listening contact changes in the phone book like adding a new contact,updating,deleting.How do I make my Android ContentObserver for ContactsContract detect a added, updated or deleted contact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ContentResolver`

```
class MyObserver extends ContentObserver {
// left blank below constructor for this Contact observer example to work
// or if you want to make this work using Handler then change below registering  //line      
public MyObserver(Handler handler) {
  super(handler);           
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
  this.onChange(selfChange, null);
  Log.e("", "~~~~~~" + selfChange);
   // Override this method to listen to any changes
}        

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
  //On Contact add/delete this method is fired
}        
}
```

Register Observer like this

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, new MyObserver());
```

Tutorial available [here](http://www.adityathakker.com/android-content-observer-react-on-content-change/)

Comment: thankxx @Ganesh Pokale In which place I have to register my content observer in my code

Comment: Add registration in onCreate